# Python - how to combine the value of the child and the father in fork?

Tags: python, arrays, fork

I would like to be able to create an array, making it build half of the father and the half of the child, i tried something like this:

```
NUM_PROC = 1
children = []
a = []

for process in range(NUM_PROC):
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid == 0:
       a.append(3)
       os._exit(0)
    else:
       a.append(2)
for i, proc in enumerate(children):
        os.waitpid(proc, 0)

print("Parent process is closing")
```

but it does not work, how could I do?(the final order of array isn't important)

the final result is :

```
a = [2]
```

i would like :

```
a= [2,3]
```

Comment: _"but it does not work_. That is not helpful. Please provide specifics about what you want it to do and what it is instead doing.

Comment: Please explain more clearly. And provide a better example.

Comment: sorry , maybe now is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the catch,

> Multiprocessing does not magically share variables amongst pool processes.

Every process in the pool has its own copy of List.

Here a.append() from any of the pool processes does not change List 'a' in the main process.